# R forecast giving results much bigger than the data

Tags: r, forecasting, economics, ardl

I'm doing some forecasts for highway traffic and some of them are not giving the results I expected. It's weird because I used the exact same code for some highways and it worked, but for this one I'm getting forecasts on the trillions (I expected 2 or 3 million vehicles).

Briefly, I'm using diff(x) in my model, so I adapt the data. Then, i use ardlDlm (with an order I got from my boss who estimated only the model before on EViews) to estimate the effect of "PIB" in "Leves" (all the other variables are dummies, that's why i remove their lags). The model is having decent results that make sense, but then I go the forecast and things get in the trillions for some reason. It shouldn't have this result, for example, the last "Leves" observation is 2.674.496, so I'm clueless here. Thanks in advance for any help.

The "Renovias" data looks like this:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR9La.png)

First 12 rows:

Date    Leves   Pesados Q1  Q2  PIB JAN FEV MAR ABR MAI JUN JUL AGO SET OUT NOV Crise   Greve   CES
01/04/1999  1106640.5   758932  1   0   60123.20    0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
01/05/1999  1218219.5   827682  1   0   60957.24    0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
01/06/1999  1109770.5   774122  1   0   62562.70    0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
01/07/1999  1222242.5   757961  1   0   61539.71    0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
01/08/1999  1078172.5   880780  1   0   61903.36    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
01/09/1999  1120372.5   863346  1   0   60594.21    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
01/10/1999  1149853.5   869919  1   0   63358.14    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
01/11/1999  1094217.0   818265  1   0   65177.98    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
01/12/1999  1227005.0   821046  1   0   64274.77    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
01/01/2000  1160712.5   780890  1   0   59871.67    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
01/02/2000  1015884.0   794188  1   0   59273.23    0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
01/03/2000  1152619.0   843165  1   0   59664.81    0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

The script:

```
library(openxlsx)
library(egcm)
library(aTSA)
library(nortest)
library(data.table)
library(dynamac)
library(AER)
library(dynlm)
library(readxl)
library(stargazer)
library(scales)
library(urca)
library(dLagM)
library(dplyr)
library(ggfortify)
library(data.table)
library(nardl)
library(zoo)
library(vars)
library(neuralnet)
library(DMwR2)
library(TTR)
library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(ggplot2)
library(writexl)
library(tseries)
library(ecm)
library(knitr)
library(plotly)
library(tictoc)
library(ARDL)

#DADOS ----

Renovias <- read_excel("Ecopistas/ABCR/data.xlsx", sheet = "Renovias", range = "A1:t298")
data <- Renovias[c(1:(nrow(Renovias)-48)),-1]

d_Leves = diff(data$Leves)
d_Pesados = diff(data$Pesados)
d_PIB = diff(data$PIB)
d_data = data[-1,]
d_data$Leves = d_Leves
d_data$Pesados = d_Pesados
d_data$PIB = d_PIB

#LEVES ------

newdata_leves <- Renovias[c((nrow(data)):nrow(Renovias)), c(4:19)]

PIBdn = diff(newdata_leves$PIB)

newdata_leves = newdata_leves[-1,]

newdata_leves$PIB = PIBdn

transposed_newdata_leves <- t(newdata_leves)

model_leves = dLagM::ardlDlm(formula = Leves ~ PIB +
                               JAN + FEV + MAR + ABR + MAI + JUN +
                               JUL + AGO + SET + OUT + NOV + Crise + Greve + Q1 + Q2,
                             data = d_data, p = 1, q = 2,
                             remove = list(p = list(JAN=c(1:1),FEV=c(1:1),MAR=c(1:1), ABR=c(1:1),
                                                    MAI=c(1:1), JUN=c(1:1),JUL=c(1:1), AGO=c(1:1),
                                                    SET=c(1:1), OUT=c(1:1),NOV=c(1:1), Crise = c(1:1),
                                                    Greve=c(1:1), Q1 = c(1:1), Q2 = c(1:1)
                             )))

summary(model_leves)
MAPE(model_leves)
model_leves[["model"]][["coefficients"]][is.na(model_leves[["model"]][["coefficients"]])] <- 0

prediction_leves <- forecast(model = model_leves,
                             x = transposed_newdata_leves,
                             h = nrow(newdata_leves), interval = TRUE, level = 0.95, nSim = 1000)
```

I'm sorry I can't give the full data, it's a problem I'm having on work so anything further is really confidential.

Comment: You need to include some data, even if you make 10-rows of fake data that fails you forecast too. But without data it is hard to solve a problem where the problem could be code or data based

Comment: thats not the recommended way to share data; for example, I can't access that. but I could if it was just text embedded in your post, a la the standard dput() recommendation. ... but before you take any effort to remedy, does the 12 rows when used with your code produce a problematic result ? if not there would be no point.

Comment: Added some data in the post